# show alert on response.render, in EJS template, if statement not working in EJS

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I have a signup port request and when that is complete it renders an EJS template with a verbal signupRequest: 'success'.

But when I go to localhost:8888/ then it gives me this error


ERROR:

```
    ReferenceError: /Users/oliver_christensen/Documents/codeFiles/nodejs-app-1/views/index.ejs:36
    34| </style>
    35| <body>
 >> 36|     <% if (signupRequest) { %> 
    37|        <script>alert('You have been signed up successfully!');</script> 
    38|     <% } %>
    39|     

signupRequest is not defined
```

When I have been on the signup.html and send the post request. Then it works and index.ejs rendres.

It just when you go to the localhost:8888/ without the post signup request, then it gives me the error...

---

am I doing something wrong or, thanks for the help :)

---

My code:

```
server.set('view engine', 'ejs');

server.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

server.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index');
});

server.post('/signup', (req, res) => {
    // at the end of signup requset function
    res.render('index', {signupRequest: 'success'});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think its because for POST and GET method you are referencing the same template. The problem is when you go to GET localhost:8888/ you did not pass the second parameter `{signupRequest: false}`. Set to `false` to not trigger the alert.

```
server.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index', {signupRequest: false});
});
```

Comment: But I don't understand why my code is not working. On ejs.co, ejs website. On the site is there an example of an if statement.
`<% if (user) { %>
  <h2><%= user.name %></h2>
<% } %>`
Dosent this if statement just check if the user veribel exsits?